# Laravel append URI in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Hi I want to append the uri in laravel route function.

e.g we have  /search?type=listing

```
//how do i can achieve this with 

route('search',['type'=>'listing'])
```

Once the we are on the search. I want to have all the variable appended to search like

`type=listing&query=blah blah`

Answer (score 9):

If I get you right, you want to save all query parameters. Use `Request::query()` to get it and then merge with your new parameters.

```
route('search', array_merge(\Request::query(), ['type' => 'listing'])));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a named route and want to generate url with query params then:

```
route('route_name', ['param1' => 'value', 'param2' => 'value']);
```

In your case you can do this with

```
route('search',['type'=>'listing','subject' => ['blah'],[....]])
```